# Join two tables based on two columns that equal each other

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have two datatables, all fields are strings:

```
Table1
Branch
AccountNumber
Name
Address
City
State
Zip

Table2
Branch
AccountNumber
Address2
City2
State2
Zip2
```

I need to join the two tables together by the branch column and account number column and end up with 1 table with all columns in it.

I found this in another post and couldn't work out the details:

```
var collection = from t1 in iom.DataTable.AsEnumerable()
         join t2 in iob.DataTable.AsEnumerable()
            on t1["Branch"] equals t2["Branch"] &
            t1["AccountNumber"] equals t2["AccountNumber"]
         select new { Branch = t1["Branch"], AccountNumber = t2["AccountNumber"] };
```

I have two issues with this:

1. The & isn't working, how do I do two equals?
2. I'd like to return both tables together without having to specify each column. I have quite a few, I did not list them all above. Is that possible?

Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: 1. How about `&&`   2.not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` operator doesn't needed in this approach. You should rewrite your query as

```
var collection = from t1 in iom.DataTable.AsEnumerable()
         join t2 in iob.DataTable.AsEnumerable()
            on new { Branch = t1["Branch"], AccountNumber = t1["AccountNumber"] } equals 
             new { Branch = t2["Branch"], AccountNumber = t2["AccountNumber"] }
         select new { Branch = t1["Branch"], AccountNumber = t2["AccountNumber"] };
```

Comment: I'm confused by the new t1, t1 equals t1, t2? that on purpose?

Comment: Ty for fixing that. It's telling me the Anonymous type projection initializer should be a simple name or member access expression on the t1["Branch"] etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It cannot build anonymous type, cause he doesn't know names of properties. It cannot get them from `t1[]` expression. So, you should directly write them. Answer edited.